# How to use check for session and http referer?

Tags: php

I'd like to check for both session and http referer but it's not working for me.

First page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = '1';
?>
```

Second page:

```
<?php
session_start();
  if(!strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], "some referer")){

    die(header("Location: my site"));
  }

  if(!isset($_SESSION['something'])){

      die(header("Location: my site"));
  }

session_destroy();
// rest code
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are experiencing unwanted [type conversion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting).

[`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the index of the (partial) match inside the string. If you are checking for exactly the referer you want, it's returning `0` and evaluating to `false`, thus entering the condition.

Check for the return type of `strpos` explicitly either by:

```
if (is_bool(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], "some referer")))
```

This means it returned false so it wasn't found, or more to the point:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], "some referer") === FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((!strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], "some referer")) || !isset($_SESSION['something'])){
    die(header("Location: my site"));
}
```

i think you need this condition